# Not able to unit test a spring factory class using Junit

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to unit test a class with Spring JUnit and getting following exception.

My ProductDaoFactory class is a singleton class  with just one non-static factory method in it.

**Error Log:**

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 43 more
```

**ProductDaoFactoryTest.java**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ProductDaoFactoryTest {

    @Test
    public void testProductDaoFactory() {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        ProductDaoFactory productDaoFactory = (ProductDaoFactory) applicationContext.getBean("productDaoFactory");
        assertNotNull(productDaoFactory);
        applicationContext.close();
    }

}
```

**ProductDaoFactory.java**

```
public final class ProductDaoFactory {

    private static final ProductDaoFactory INSTANCE = new ProductDaoFactory();
    private String daoType;

    //so cannot new an intance
    private ProductDaoFactory() {
    }

    //singleton
    public static ProductDaoFactory getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void setDaoType(String daoType) {
        this.daoType = daoType;
    }

    //factory method
    public ProductDao getProductDao() {
        ProductDao productDao = null;

        if ("jdbc".equalsIgnoreCase(daoType)) {
            productDao = new ProductDaoJdbcImpl();
        } else if ("ibatis".equalsIgnoreCase(daoType)) {
            productDao = new ProductDaoIBatisImpl();
        } else if ("hibernate".equalsIgnoreCase(daoType)) {
            productDao = new ProductDaoHibernateImpl();
        }

        return productDao;
    }
}
```

**WEB-INF/application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
.....       
">

    <bean id="productDaoFactory" class="com.ministore.dao.factory.ProductDaoFactory" factory-method="getInstance"></bean>  
    <bean id="productDao" factory-bean="productDaoFactory" factory-method="getProductDao">
        <property name="daoType" value="jdbc" />
    </bean>  


    <!-- DATASOURCES AND DAO LAYER -->
    <!-- using JEE namespace for lookup -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/ministore-db" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: `WEB-INF/application-context.xml` is not on the classpath during tests.

Comment: Can you please guide on how to fix this ?

Comment: Move the file somewhere where it's visible. If you're using Maven it would be under "src/main/resources/".